# Gmap removing some informations

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

Is it possible to remove the names of the peaks along with their height and marking?

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.CzechTuristMapProvider.Instance;
    GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Maps .
Find the place you want to report for review.
Select the place Suggest an edit. Close or remove.
Choose the reason the place should be removed.
Click Submit

Comment: He is talking about remove it programmatically, not in google maps

Comment: Elikill58 exactly.